# Exported function in C++ COM DLL not found from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, com

I have an existing COM DLL that is currently accessed (just one function) through a VB wrapper class and called from a C# class.

I'm trying to add callbacks into my C# code (4 separate callbacks).  My chosen approach is the only one that I've found but I'm having issues.

It says "Unable to find an entry point named 'InitDotNet' in DLL 'xxxx'.

### My DLL header file:

```
extern "C"
{
#define DLL __declspec(dllexport)
typedef void (__stdcall * CB_func1)(int);
typedef void (__stdcall * CB_func2)(char *);

DLL void InitDotNet(CB_func1 func1, CB_func2 func2);
}

...

class CComInterface : public CCmdTarget
...
   afx_msg void mainCall(short parm1, LPCTSTR parm2);
...
```

### My DLL C++ file:

```
...
CB_func1  func1Function;
CB_func2  func2Function;
...
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CComInterface, CCmdTarget)
...
BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP(CComInterface, CCmdTarget)
   DISP_FUNCTION(CComInterface, "mainCall", mainCall, VT_EMPTY, VTS_I2 VTS_BSTR)
END_DISPATCH_MAP()
...
IMPLEMENT_OLECREATE(CComInterface, "MyDll.Interface", ...)

...
void CComInterface::mainCall(short parm1, LPCTSTR parm2)
{
   ...

   // at various times call func1Functoin and func2Function

   ...
}

DLL void InitDotNet(CB_func1 func1, CB_func2 func2)
{
   func1Function = func1;
   func2Function = func2;
}
```

### My VB wrapper looks like this:

```
Public Class MyWrapperClass
   Private Shared Protocol As Object = CreateObject("MyDll.Interface")

   Public Shared Sub mainCall(ByVal parm1 As Short, ByVal parm2 As String)
      Protocol.mainCall(parm1, parm2)
   End Sub
End Class
```

### My C# code looks like this:

```
...
using System.Runtime.InteropServices
namespace MyNamespace
{
   public partial class MyForm : AnotherForm
   {
      ...
      [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public delegate void func1Callback(int value);

      [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public delegate void func2Callback(string value);

      [DllImport("mycppdll.dll")]
      public static extern void InitDotNet([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] func1Callback f1c,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] func2Callback f2c);
      ...
      private void MyFunc()
      {
         func1Callback f1c = 
            (value) =>
            {
               // work here
            };
         func2Callback f2c =
            (value) =>
            {
               // work here
            };

         InitDotNet(f1c, f2c);

         MyWrapperDll.MyWrapperClass.mainCall(1, "One");

}
```

Anybody have any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is not the cause of your entry-point error, but note that you need to retain a reference to the delegates stored in `f1c` and `f2c` for as long as the unmanaged code might call them. Otherwise, they may be garbage-collected before the unmanaged code invokes them. If the unmanaged code will not call them after `InitDotNet()` returns, then you need to call `GC.KeepAlive()` on both delegate objects after the `InitDotNet()` call. Otherwise, make sure you store them on a field somewhere.

Comment: It looks like the entrypoint you defined in your Dllimport statement isn't correct, or runtime can't find it for whatever reason. Are you familiar with dumpbin? If you run dumpbin /exports on the .dll in question, you can see what the entrypoint names actually are. Edit: or what cdhowie said. You can still check on the entrypoints though, just for completeness sake :)

Comment: Can you just confirm what DLL is defined to be in the declaration of InitDotNet?

Comment: Why does InitDotNet take long instead of CB_func1 and CB_func2? Why is InitDotNot not marked __stdcall (default is cdecl) when you've declared it as such in the interop signature (note: this is probably why the runtime can't find the export; calling convention changes the exported name)?  You need to tell the runtime to marshal func2Callback's parameter as char*, e.g. [MarshalAs(UnmangedType.LPStr)].  You need to keep the delegates alive so the GC doesn't collect them (it knows nothing about native code; see cdhowie's comment).

Comment: p.s. given that 64-bit Windows is LLP64, the long data type in C++ is 4 bytes in size for that platform.  The stdcall naming convention will export InitDotNet as "_InitDotNet@8" if you use two longs.  A 64-bit runtime will expect an export of "_InitDotNet@16" because it expects pointers; thus, InitDotNet's parameters should be pointers, not long.

Comment: Some quick answers (haven't finished reviewing everything yet): My model for this was this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/318140/How-to-make-a-callback-to-Csharp-from-C-Cplusplus  (it explains the use of longs, but I'll try your suggestion).  Also, this is on a 32 bit machine and for a 32 bit build.  (Changing longs to the particular data type didn't change anything, still entry point not found).

Comment: I'm just going to write up my comments as an answer; I believe your solution lies somewhere in there.

Comment: @glace, I used Dependency Walker and it shows "InitDotNet" as an entry point exported as "C".  Does dumpbin provide more information than DW does?

Comment: @TheMathemagician, DLL is "#define DLL __declspec(dllexport)", its at the top of the code sample.

Comment: @Peter Huene - again, I'm going based on the link I showed earlier (DoWork method).  As far as keeping things alive, having them global won't do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issues I see:

1. `InitDotNet` takes long instead of `CB_func1` and `CB_func2`.  This is a two-fold problem for 64-bit versions of your program: it leads to an exported name mismatch for stdcall functions and, worse, it can cause pointer truncation if `InitDotNet` somehow manages to get called.
2. InitDotNet is not marked `__stdcall`.  The default calling convention is cdecl.  The cdecl naming convention is "prefix with underscore", so the exported name is "_InitDotNet".  However, the stdcall naming convention is "prefix with underscore, postfix with @ followed by the size of the arguments, in bytes", so the expected exported name would be "_InitDotNet@8" (with the current signature of taking two longs).  You should use a program like dumpbin or [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to view the names of the functions exported by your DLL. **This mismatch is likely the reason the runtime can't find `InitDotNet`, assuming 32-bit Windows**.  You should not be specifying `EntryPoint` to the `DllImport` attribute if this is corrected (the runtime will figure out the appropriate name automatically).
3. As pointed out by cdhowie in the comments, you need to keep the two delegates you're passing to the native code "alive".  The .NET garbage collector is incapable of knowing that the function pointers are being stored by the native code.  To prevent the garbage collector from collecting them, keep a reference to the delegates around (such as in a field for an object that is guaranteed to outlive the native code's use for them) or use a `GCHandle`.  Note if you use a `GCHandle`: you do not need to use a pinned handle; the function pointer that is actually passed to your code is a stub and the stub remains in the same place even if the delegate is moved by the garbage collector.  However, the stub is deleted when the delegate is collected, so it is vital to ensure the delegate does not get collected until the native code no longer needs the callbacks.

Comment: thanks, have to run out but I'll muck around with your suggestions tomorrow and update on how it went.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: That `const` actually is part of the signature.  It's top-level const, i.e. `wchar_t* const`, that is excluded.

Comment: I meant in terms of the marshaller, not in the language.  The marshaller can't marshal "constness".

Comment: Actually, I forgot that the default CharSet is Ansi (really? it's 2013 people!).  Removed the paragraph entirely.

Comment: Very strange.  depends says that exported function name is "InitDotNet".  Not "_InitDotNet" as you suggest.  Regarding your point #1, I changed the code to reflect the function points as you suggested.  Still have same issue.  I also removed the specification of the Entrypoint - also reflected in the updated code above.  Don't seem to have dumpbin on my system, Have VS 2008 and it didn't come with it.

Comment: So it turns out that my real problem was that I had an old version of that DLL that was being loaded before mine.  All my changes weren't taking hold.  In any event, all the comments above are appropriate and helped in my understanding - thanks.  Going to mark this one as solved since your suggestions helped me find the actual cause.

Answer (score 1):

COM's way of passing callbacks is interfaces. Trying to match unmanaged function pointers with .NET delegates is complicated and error-prone, as you've experienced. Interfaces are not as practical as delegates, but still better than function pointers.

So if I were you I'd put the callbacks in a COM interface exported by the COM DLL:

(The following is IDL code, which must go in the .idl file associated with the C++ project.)

```
interface ISomeObject : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT DoTask1([in] int i);
    HRESULT DoTask2([in] BSTR s);
}
```

Then build the C++ project, and add the type library as a reference from the C# project. If the type library is registered, you can add it by right-clicking the C# project name in the **Solution Explorer** pane of Visual Studio, select **Add Reference**, go to the **COM** tab, look for the name of the type library and add it as a reference.

Once you have added a reference to the type library, you can use the COM interface as if it were a C# interface:

```
class MyForm : AnotherForm, ISomeObject
{
      // ISomeObject methods:
    public void DoTask1(int i) { ... }
    public void DoTask2(string s) { ... }

    ...
}
```

Then InitDotNet would take a ISomeObject pointer, and the C# code would simply call it by passing **this**:

C++:

```
ISomeObject* g_pSomeObject;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall InitDotNet(ISomeObject* o)
{
    g_pSomeObject = o;
}
```

C#:

```
[DllImport("mycppdll.dll")]
private static extern void InitDotNet(ISomeObject o);

private void DoInitDotNet()
{
    // The following works because MyForm implements ISomeObject
    InitDotNet(this);
}
```

But I would also make InitDotNet a method of a COM interface and not a global function.

Last but not least, what's the purpose of the VB class? If it's only purpose is only to wrap the COM class, you don't need it: COM classes/interfaces are directly consumable from C#.

Comment: I'm wondering if you are assuming that my DLL is a C# dll.  It is an older DLL written in c++.  From searching around, this method was all I could find in general approach.  And yes, the VB class is just a wrapper because the assumption was that there was no other way to access the COM method in the C++ DLL.  You can see above the C++ code - can you suggest an architecture that allows me to call the "mainCall" method passing callbacks in the way you suggest above?  Perhaps a sample?

Comment: No, I know the DLL is a C++ COM DLL. But are you saying that it's a third-party DLL and you can't modify it? Because to do what I suggested you definitely need to modify it.

Comment: I can modify it.  I would need some explanation though on how the c++ code would interpret the interface pointer.

Comment: OK, I added more stuff to explain how to do it.